# TypeScript - Navigate dropdown listitems using keyboard

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-2016

I'm working on an open-source project and have encountered a bug. I'm not able to navigate the dropdown list items using the keyboard (arrow key/tab). I've written the keyboard-navigation logic, but not quite sure of how to implement it. Below is the code snippet.

```
.
.
.

const TopNavPopoverItem: FC<ComponentProps> = ({closePopover, description, iconSize, iconType, title, to}) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleButtonClick = (): void => {
    history.push(to);
    closePopover();
  };

  const useKeyPress = function (targetKey: any) { // where/how am I supposed to use this function?
    const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);
    function downHandler(key: any) {
      if (key === targetKey) {
        setKeyPressed(true);
      }
    }
    const upHandler = (key: any) => {
      if (key === targetKey) {
        setKeyPressed(false);
      }
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
      window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
      };
    });
    return keyPressed;
  };


  return (
    <button className="TopNavPopoverItem" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
      <Icon className="TopNavPopoverItem__icon" icon={iconType} size={iconSize} />
      <div className="TopNavPopoverItem__right">
        <span className="TopNavPopoverItem__title">{title}</span>
        <span className="TopNavPopoverItem__description">{description}</span>
      </div>
    </button>
  );
};
```

Any workaround or fixes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your goal for `useKeyPress`? It appears to be a custom hook for React; how are you expecting consumers to utilize it? You may want to look at the [documentation for building custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)..

Answer (score 0):

A custom hook should always be defined **at the top level of your file**.  It cannot be inside of a component.  The component *uses* the hook, but doesn't *own* the hook.

You have a hook which takes a key name as an argument and returns a `boolean` indicating whether or not that key is currently being pressed.  It's the right idea, but it has some mistakes.

When you start adding better TypeScript types you'll see that the argument of your event listeners needs to be the **event** -- not the key.  You can access the key as a property of the event.

(Note: Since we are attaching directly to the window, the event is a DOM `KeyboardEvent` rather than a `React.KeyboardEvent` synthetic event.)

Your `useEffect` hook should have some dependencies so that it doesn't run on every render.  It depends on the `targetKey`. I'm writing my code in CodeSandbox where I get warnings about "exhaustive dependencies", so I'm also adding `setKeyPressed` as a dependency and moving the two handlers inside the `useEffect`.

I see that you have one handler as `function` and one as a `const`.  FYI it really doesn't matter which you use in this case.

Our revised hook looks like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useKeyPress = (targetKey: string) => {
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const downHandler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (event.key === targetKey) {
          setKeyPressed(true);
        }
      };

      const upHandler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (event.key === targetKey) {
          setKeyPressed(false);
        }
      };

      // attach the listeners to the window.
      window.addEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
      window.addEventListener("keyup", upHandler);

      // remove the listeners when the component is unmounted.
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
        window.removeEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
      };
    },
    // re-run the effect if the targetKey changes.
    [targetKey, setKeyPressed]
  );

  return keyPressed;
};
```

---

I don't know you intend to use this hook, but here's a dummy example.  We show a red box on the screen while the spacebar is pressed, and show a message otherwise.

Make sure that the key name that you use when you call the hook [is the correct key name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).  For the spacebar it is `" "`.

```
import { useKeyPress } from "./useKeyPress";

export default function App() {
  const isPressedSpace = useKeyPress(" ");

  return (
    <div>
      {isPressedSpace ? (
        <div style={{ background: "red", width: 200, height: 200 }} />
      ) : (
        <div>Press the Spacebar to show the box.</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/usekeypress-react-custom-hook-ws5oq?file=/src/App.tsx)